# Javascript scoping issue, object has no data after assigning it

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using NodeJS to create an express endpoint that will retrieve the metadata from my images stored on my server. I have the following code for the logic of the endpoint:

```
/*
 * Gallery Controller
 */

var fs = require('fs'),
    _ = require('underscore'),
    im = require('imagemagick');

/**
 * List paths to images stored in selected gallery
 */
exports.list = function(req, res) {
    var dir = 'public/images/' + req.params.id;

    fs.readdir(dir, function(err, files) {
        if (err) return res.send({error: 'No gallery found with provided id'}, 404);

        if (files.length > 0) {
            var collection = [],
                myData = {};

            files.forEach(function(file) {
                if(file === '.DS_Store') return;

                im.readMetadata( dir + '/' + file, function(err, metadata) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    myData = metadata;
                    console.log(myData); // logs as object with expected data
                });

                console.log(myData); // logs as empty {}
                collection.push(myData);
            });

            console.log(collection); // logs as [ {}, {} ]

            res.json(collection, 200);
        } else {
            res.json({error: 'Selected gallery is empty'}, 404);
        }
    });
};
```

I've listed what the logs appear as in the terminal, why am I getting this scoping issue? I can't seem to wrap my head around it. If I try to `return` the `metadata` obj and assign it to the `var`, I get the following error: `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module, it'll improve your life in many ways.

The problem you are having is a common one I see, and it is that your loop is asynchronous, but you are treating it as something serial.

Instead of doing `files.forEach`, you want to loop them asynchronously and then do some more stuff when the looping is done. You can use `async.each` for that.

```
async.each(files, function (file, next) {
  if (file === '.DS_Store') return next();

  im.readMetadata(path.join(dir, file), function (e, data) {
    collection.push(data);
    next(err);
  });
}, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log(collection);
});
```

As an alternative, an even more appropriate solution might be to use `async.map`.

```
async.map(files, function (file, next) {
  if (file === '.DS_Store') return next();

  im.readMetadata(path.join(dir, file), next);
}, function (err, collection) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log(collection);
});
```

Comment: You need to call `next` when the filename equals `.DS_Store` too :)

Comment: It's too bad `async.map` doesn't have some way of telling it that some elements should just be skipped (like the `.DS_Store` case, which leaves an empty element in the `collection` array).

Comment: Yeah. That's a shame, I guess he should filter that out before the async loop.

Comment: Or filter it out of the `collection` afterwards.

Comment: Ah, that's great, this works perfect. It has the empty entry in the array, but I can filter it out as mentioned

Answer (score 1):

You need to restructure your code:

```
files.forEach(function(file, i) {
  if (file === '.DS_Store') return; // see text

  im.readMetadata( dir + '/' + file, function(err, metadata) { 
    if (err) throw err;
    collection.push(metadata);
    if (i === files.length - 1) {
      res.json(collection); // see text
    }
  });
});
```

The reason is that the metadata is only available when the callback function to `readMetadata` is called; that's how asynchronous I/O works in Node.

In that callback, you add the metadata to the collection. If the iteration of the `forEach` has reached the final element (`i` is the index of the current element, when its value is one less than the size of the array, it's the last element), the response is sent.

Two issues:

- if `.DS_Store` is the last/only file in the directory, this code will fail because it will never send back a response; I'll leave it to you to deal with that case ;)
- `res.json` will, by default, return a `200` status so you don't have to specify it; if you *do* want to specify a status, it needs to be `res.json(200, collection)` (arguments swapped)